# Can Eclipse Be Used To Find All Deprecated Method Calls?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Does Eclipse have a feature that lets you search a project to find all calls to deprecated methods?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can set the compiler to generate errors or warnings (your choice) for any usage of deprecated API.

> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> *Deprecated and restricted API* section.

Then, each use of a deprecated method or API will show up as an error/warning in the Problems view.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to page or scroll the list of errors or warnings? I have more than it can show me at once and can't seem to find a way to show them all.

Comment: In the Problems view, click on the View Menu (the triangle icon) ... you can change the number of visible items under Preferences. You can also change which Types of problems are shown under Configure Contents.

Comment: This is a ridiculous comment, but note that this only works if you're running your code through Eclipse as well.  I'm writing through Eclipse and running through a separate program, so I don't get any messages.  -1 to me for noobishness.

Answer (score 12):

*[Updating eight years later, for current versions of Eclipse, with screenshots.]*

**First, build your projects.** Once you've built your projects, the Problems view includes deprecations by default. You can group all the deprecations together.

**To show the Problems view,** use *Window>Show View>Problems*.

**If deprecations don't appear after the next step**, you can configure them in Preferences under *Java>Compiler>Errors/Warnings*.

**Group deprecations together** using the Problem view menu. Start by clicking the control circled below.

[image: Menu to gruop by Java problem type]

Once you've done that, open the "Deprecation" subtree. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the grep facilities under 'Search -> File'. Eclipse can do a recursive search for `@deprecated` after you check on the 'consider derived resources' option box.