# eclipse php find deprecated

Tags: php, eclipse

I have to upgrade a Joomla 1.5 component to Joomla 1.7 and would like to search for all the deprecated method calls in my code(at the moment i see those function with a strikethrough),

i've seen it is possible to do in Java([stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233593/can-eclipse-be-used-to-find-all-deprecated-method-calls)),

but can't find out **how to do it in PHP**(there is no Preferences, *Php*, Compiler, Errors/Warnings, Deprecated and restricted API section)

Using Eclipse Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415 with the php language installed.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a bash script that does just that: http://www.typofree.org/article/archive/2011/may/title/check-your-php-code-for-deprecated-ini-directives-and-functions/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a roundabout way of doing it, but it's the best I can figure.

The function comments for the deprecated thing has a @deprecated tag (defined by the phpdoc standard) which is read by the scanner but only used to show deprecated usage, which is useless if you're trying to do a top-to-bottom scan.

But here's another approach.

Preferences, PHP->Validation->Task Tags. Add a new tag with "@deprecated". Then rebuild the project (you should be prompted to do so). This will grab all the definitions of deprecated things and dump them into tasks.

Open the task window and sort/filter/whatever until you have just the deprecated tags for the source code you care about.

Double click on each entry to go to the deprecated definition. Highlight the thing being defined in the source code, right click and choose References->Project (or working set or whatever). This will bring up a list of all the usage in your project. You can now go through and remediate them one-by-one.

If you become familiar with the task view, you can use it to tick off the remediations as you complete them. But that's left as a RTFM exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

I am not sure whether this is helpful to you, because i am just hiding the errors and not searching/removing it.

Comment: 10x, but you have to execute all possible scripts to see it this way

Comment: you can register a function which is triggered everytime an error/warning/exception is thrown and then write them in a file, then just run your website, see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 0):

Windows > Preferences > PHP > Syntax Coloring > Select Deprecated members > Select enabled