# How to find java deprecated apis for third party tools?

Tags: java, eclipse, deprecated

How to find **java deprecated apis** for **third party tools**? 
And how to **print output** all warnings of deprecated apis in to **text or excel or csv file**.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Eclipse Be Used To Find All Deprecated Method Calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233593/can-eclipse-be-used-to-find-all-deprecated-method-calls)

Answer (score 1):

If **third party tools** means third party jar files then do following:

1. Add your jar file in classpath of your project.+
2. Check `Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Deprecated and restricted API section.`

For copying all the warning into text file:
There is currently no way to export warnings, but you can copy it any paste it into any text file.

1. Open Problem View in your eclipse
2. Select warnings in problem view.
3. Right click-> copy
4. Paste it into some text file.